# How to set background of ImageView in a Notification's RemoteView in Android?

Tags: android, background, imageview, remoteview

I've transplant Android's Notification, How to set background of ImageView in a RemoteView of Notification, and set it to transparent?

I tried

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.icon, "setBackgroundResource", 0x00000000);
```

but it not worked.

I think the problem is I can't get R.id.yourFrame from Android framework in another app process. So the code above is just apply for the current widget process.

So how can I get the compiled R.id.icon as a int? I want to try in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`remoteView.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00);`

or

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.yourFrame, "setBackgroundColor",
    android.R.color.transparent);
```

or

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.yourFrame,"setBackgroundColor",
    android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Also you can set background transparent of any layout or any view or any component by adding this code in XML:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: I've tried but still can't set the ImageView's background. Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is I can't get R.id.yourFrame from Android framework in another app process. So the code above is just apply for the current widget process.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use following to set background of ImageView for remoteview

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.imgViewFollowed, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.icon_followed);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_main);

views.setInt(R.id.image1, "setBackgroundResource", android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);
```

its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change the colours of your view by

```
remoteview.setInt(R.id.viewId, "setBackgroundColor", color)
```

Then you update the change to your RemoteViews by

```
val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
notificationManager.notify(ID.SERVICE_ID, notification)
```

Hope that help you.